# non-object error with fetchColumn() in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch

I'm getting a `Call to a member function fetchColumn() on a non-object` error when I'm executing my query with a mysql prepared statement on PHP

```
$result= $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id_1 = ? AND id_2 = ?");
$result->execute(array($id_1,$id_2))->fetchColumn();
echo count($result);
```

What is the reason for this error? Am I writing the statement incorrectly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) returns a boolean to check whether your query has executed properly. You can only chain method calls if each methods returns the reference of your `PDOStatement` object. You want to do this

```
$result= $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id_1 = ? AND id_2 = ?");
$result->execute(array($id_1,$id_2));
echo $result->fetchColumn();
```